# Overriding a trait method in Laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, traits

I cannot override a method of a trait in my Controller class. Here is an example of my trait method:

```php
protected function resetPassword($user, $password)
{
    $user->password = bcrypt($password);

    $user->save();

    Auth::login($user);
}
```

And here is my Controller:

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;


class PasswordController extends Controller
{
    use ResetsPasswords {
        resetPassword as newReset;
    }

    /**
     * Create a new password controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    protected function resetPassword($user, $password)
    {

    }
}
```

I found one example, but I am not sure that I am on a right way.

Comment: No, but the method in the trait is working.. I need to rewrite it in my controller.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP override trait method of parent class's trait](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36431292/php-override-trait-method-of-parent-classs-trait)

Answer (score 9):

As you have already done it yourself, you need to alias framework trait's `resetPassword` method and then implement your own:

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;

class PasswordController extends Controller
{
    use ResetsPasswords {
        resetPassword as frameworkResetPassword;
    }

    protected function resetPassword($user, $password)
    {
        // Do your custom password reset logic here
        $user->password = bcrypt($password);
        $user->save();
        Auth::login($user);

        // Then you can pass the work over to framework's implementation
        // if that's needed.
        // $this->frameworkResetPassword($user, $password);
    }
}
```

By the way, Laravel's own [password reset functionality](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/ResetsPasswords.php#L103-L114) supports logging users in.